# Programmatically entering text in New York Times Crosswords

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I would like to programmatically fill in answers to clues in NYT crossword via Java/Selenium. I cannot do it via the standard sendKeys() method. I get errors such as "element not interactable: element has zero size" etc.  It appears that the only way to set the value is via javascript. I tried this [jsfiddle][1]to simulate keyboard typing but it simply does not work.

The question is how do I set the value of a cell to a value?

As a full example to the crossword, look at crossword example

The bellow focuses on a single clue:

```
<-- The bellow describes the clue number; in this case 3 -->
<text x="71.00" y="14.50" text-anchor="start" font-size="11.00">
  <text class="xwd__cell--hidden" aria-live="polite">
  </text>3
</text>

<-- The bellows describes the answer to the clue; in this case N -->
<text x="85.50" y="33.25" text-anchor="middle" font-size="22.00">
  <text class="xwd__cell--hidden" aria-live="polite">N
  </text>N
</text>
```

Tried using sendKeys() method with java, expecting the cell to have the letter I sent.  What happens is that I get error such as "element not interactable: element has zero size"

Comment: Doesn't the `<text>` elements contains _**3**_ & _**N**_

Comment: show some code please

Comment: The 3 is there (not user input) - it is the cell number.  The N was manually entered by myself (via the crossword page itself) as I was trying to debug the issue

Comment: I think the issue is that <text> is not a form input so you can't treat it like one. I can't tell what you're doing though

Comment: True, the <text> tag is not a form of input.  Is there way to alter the html text at runtime ? E.g. set <text>X</text> at runtime